# How to get WMS layer title instead of layer name from Geoserver?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms

I specified the raster file with "name" and "title" in Geoserver.

For example, I have these in Geoserver:

```
name,  Title  
AT:usa, "This is a map of USA"
```

Can I return the title ("This is a map of USA" ) as the layer name in Openlayers layer switcher when I call the WMS service for this layer by name? By default, it shows "usa" in the layer switcher.

Comment: What is the value of the first param passed to the openlayers layer constructor? I bet it is "usa". Now do you want do dynamically fetch the layer name from geoserver?

Comment: Do you think this is the only way?

Comment: There are 2 ways: dynamic (difficult) and static (easy)

Comment: I was expecting the title parameter would come with the post back WMS. So could you tell me how to do static one? Thanks! @unicoletti

Comment: You can parse the WMS GetCapabilities response to get the name and title of the layers in the service.  `name` is for computer interaction, `title` is for humans to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are creating your [OpenLayers WMS](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/WMS-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.WMS.OpenLayers.Layer.WMS) layer as follows:

```
var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("This is a map if USA",
                               "http://yourgeoserver/geoserver/wms",
                               {layers: "AT:usa"});
```

then the first parameter is the layer name that will be displayed in the layer switcher. Simply set it to whatever you like it to be.

Comment: I think this is an easy way to get around. That is how I did it exactly. Thanks!